# iOS QuickLook QLPreviewController can it display page number of DOC file

Tags: ios, file, location, qlpreviewcontroller

When viewing a PDF file, QuickView can show the individual pages. Can this be done with MS Office files too (DOC, PPT)? I want a way to know how many pages/slides are in the document and what page I am currently viewing.

Thanks for the help!